# Ruby 2D Array Assignment Possible Bug?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm experiencing the following. I expect only the first sub-element of the first sub array to be assigned `"x"`, not the first element of each sub array. Can anyone explain this behaviour, and perhaps how to work around it? (Note that this may well be expected behaviour, but if it is, it contradicts my expectations.)

```
x = Array.new(3, Array.new(5))
# => [[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
x[0][0] # => nil
x[0][0] = "x"
x
# => [["x", nil, nil, nil, nil], ["x", nil, nil, nil, nil], ["x", nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

Comment: 2d_array = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(columns) }

Comment: this is not a bug.. you overlooked the doc :)

Comment: -1. Question is not clear. Where is the bug? Perhaps in your brain? And you should first explain why you expect as you wrote.

Comment: You might feel that my comment above is offensive, but that is what you are doing against Ruby (developers). If you blame someone for your own fault, then that is what you get back.

Comment: @sawa Your comment is "offensive" but mostly because my title was not as I intended. Arup's answer is helpful and not condescending like your comment. (Point, however, taken regarding being careful about formulating the title of the question.)

Comment: What is wrong is your attitude to immediately suspect the others' failure before even thinking a bit about the possibility of your own failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

workaround is :

```
x = Array.new(3) { Array.new(5) }
x[0][0] = 'a'
x # => [["a", nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

[`new(size) {|index| block }`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new)

> Here an array of the given size is created. Each element in this array is created by passing the element’s index to the given block and storing the return value.

Read also [`Common gotchas`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas)

> When sending the second parameter, the same object will be used as the value for all the array elements. Since all the Array elements store the same array `Array.new(5)`, changes to one of them will affect them all.
>
> If multiple copies are what you want, you should use the block version which uses the result of that block each time an element of the array needs to be initialized, as I did above.

Comment: @AlokAnand coming next week, we will meet.. :)

Comment: The common gotchas, which I indeed overlooked, explains why this was happening. Certainly helpful to look over.

Answer (score 0):

```
2d_array = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(columns) }
```